# One network call for each subscription

Tags: angular, observable

I am using `HTTPClient` to make `post` request but am experiencing very weird behavior when I `subscribe` to the `observable` returned by `HTTPClient`: For each `subscription`, I am getting one `post` request. Meaning, if I `subscribe` to `observable` 5 times, I am getting 5 `post` request. Extremely weird!

I am making post request in my **`serverService`** as follows:

```
  makePostReq<T>(reqObj: {url:string, body:any, headerData?:any}): Observable<T>{
    let headers = this.createHeaders(reqObj.headerData);
    reqObj.body, {headers:headers});
    return this.httpClient.post<T>(reqObj.url, reqObj.body, {headers:headers});
  }
```

In my component I am calling `makePostReq` as follows:

```
 overviewInfo$: Observable<IOverviewInfo>;
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getOverviewInfo();
  }

  getOverviewInfo() {

    console.log('getOverviewInfo...');

    let url = this.constantsService.getOverViewInfoUrl();
    let body = {
      bot_id: this.bot_id,
      platform: this.selectedChannel,
      start_date: this.start_date,
      end_date: this.end_date
    };
        this.overviewInfo$ = this.serverService.makePostReq({url, body});

/*=== Now if I subscribe to overviewInfo 5 times, I will have 5 post request=== */

        this.overviewInfo$.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value);
        });
        this.overviewInfo$.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value);
        });
        this.overviewInfo$.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value);
        });
        this.overviewInfo$.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value);
        });
        this.overviewInfo$.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value);
        });
      }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Edit:**

In reality, I am not subscribing multiple times. Rather, I am using `(overviewInfo$|async)` 5 times in my template, which is having the same effect of calling `POST` 5 times. I asked the question with multiple `subscribe` to reduce the unnecessary complexity of `async` pipe.

Comment: Of course you will. That's what subscribe is supposed to do. You can subscribe to one Observable in many places and all of them will get called once the POST completes. Your POST is not called 5 times, the response from the POST call is sent to all the subscribed callbacks, i.e. 5 in your case.

Comment: @KaushikEvani Post is called 5 time. I can see in network tab. I can attach screenshot too.

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad. I misunderstood.

Comment: So are you sure that by varying the number of subscribes, the POST calls are also varying respectively?

Comment: @KaushikEvani I am very very sure. I know its extreamly weird. But thats what it is.

Comment: @KaushikEvani Screenshot added

Comment: Yup ... just found the same answers as below with my own search as well. Apparently this is by design of Observables. Checkout this [angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22026) as well for some discussion on it.

Comment: @KaushikEvani Thanks for the link. But how do people use async pipe (multiple times) if each subscription execute the whole things all over again?

Comment: You should only use the `async` pipe once in your template, [see this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-punyg1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @Und3rTow Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're facing a cold observable. The `post` method creates an observable that waits until it is subscribed to until it fires the request.

From angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) for `post()`

> Constructs an Observable which, when subscribed, will cause the configured POST request to be executed on the server.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could use `share` operator. Each subscription will not trigger a new post request, but it will get the same data, when the post request completes. Also it will not trigger a post request before something subscribes. If you subscribe after the request completes, it should make a new one.

```
 this.overviewInfo$ = this.serverService
                          .makePostReq({url, body})
                          .pipe(share());
```

Slightly different behaviour can be achieved `multicast` operator, which will trigger the post request right away. If you subscribe after the request completes, you won't receive any data.

```
 this.overviewInfo$ = this.serverService
                          .makePostReq({url, body})
                          .pipe(multicast());
```

For good ol' promise times, you could use `toPromise` which you could `.then` any time you want.

More reading on above operators: [RxJS: Understanding the publish and share Operators](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635)

Comment: Thanks! I have always seen observables as "multiple value promise". Promises, once resolved are immutable Object. And you can use it, export it or whatever you do, upon doing `.then()` it will give you resolved value. I always though Observable do the same. I have been an angular dev for 2 years. wonder, how did I survive with this misconception.

Comment: `share` is a special alias for `multicast`, so the latter isn't exactly "the other option".

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the reason why you are subscribing to the same method multiple times in the same file. Instead you could have only one `subscription` and do all your sruff there. Your component code is calling a `makePostReq` 5 times, that is normal behaviour.

Either ways, if you want to subscribe to an observable multiple times and want to fire `http.post` only once, then `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject` suits best to your requirement.

Emit your data in service as `this._subOverviewInfo.next(res.name))`

server Service

```
private _subOverviewInfo: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
public overViewInfo$: Observable<string> = this._subOverviewInfo.asObservable();

makePostReq<T>(reqObj: {url:string, body:any, headerData?:any}): Observable<T>{
    let headers = this.createHeaders(reqObj.headerData);
    reqObj.body, {headers:headers});
    return this.httpClient.post<T>(reqObj.url, reqObj.body, {headers:headers})
    .pipe(map((res) => { 
           this._subOverviewInfo.next(res.name);  // emit subject
           return res; 
    }));
}
```

And in component

call the `makePostReq()` as it is

```
 this.serverService.makePostReq({url, body}).subscribe();
```

Instead subscribe to the `subject` emiitted by a service.

```
this.serverService.overViewInfo$.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value);
 });
 this.serverService.overViewInfo$.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value);
 });   
 this.serverService.overViewInfo$.subscribe((value) => {
          console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Please see my edit. Also my code is calling `makePostReq`  just once, not 5 times.

Comment: You are calling it once. But your subscriptions are calling it multiple times. It does not work in the same way as you are assuming.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!